# Unique contraint violation on OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `City` entity and a `Person` entity. I want to setup a `OneToMany` relationship from Person to City indicating which cities a person has lived in. Its a uni-directional OneToMany relationship from Person.

My City class looks like this

```
@Entity
public class City {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;
  ...
}
```

[link to City class code](https://github.com/adeelmahmood/jpatest-onetomany/blob/master/src/main/java/jpatest/City.java)

The person entity looks like this

```
@Entity
public class Person {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<City> livedInCities = new HashSet<City>();
   ...
}
```

[link to Person class code](https://github.com/adeelmahmood/jpatest-onetomany/blob/master/src/main/java/jpatest/Person.java#L21)

In my test I am simply creating a city first and saving it. Then creating a person and adding the saved city instance on it before saving that person. After saving the person, everything is fine.

When I add a second person and add the same city on the second person, it throws a unique constraint violation. I am not sure why this is happening because in the relationship table, this should be inserted as a new row for person 2 and city 1.
Test code

```
@Test
public void test() {

    City chicago = new City();
    chicago.setName("chicago");
    City savedChicago = cityRepo.save(chicago);

    Person john = new Person();
    john.setName("john");
    john.addCity(savedChicago);
    Person savedJohn = personRepo.save(john);

    Person tom = new Person();
    tom.setName("tom");
    tom.addCity(savedChicago);
    Person savedTom = personRepo.save(tom);

    System.out.println(savedTom);
    System.out.println(savedJohn);

}
```

[link to Test code](https://github.com/adeelmahmood/jpatest-onetomany/blob/master/src/test/java/jpatest/RepositoryTests.java)

> 2015-07-02 18:11:21.026  WARN 5473 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
>   2015-07-02 18:11:21.026 ERROR 5473 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_B6XKGKBT91IXB0WE6N030RFPQ_INDEX_C ON PUBLIC.PERSON_LIVED_IN_CITIES(LIVED_IN_CITIES_ID) VALUES (1, 1)"; SQL statement:

The complete project for this is available at 
https://github.com/adeelmahmood/jpatest-onetomany

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't have a `@OneToMany` relationship here but a `@ManyToMany` as each person may have lived in more than one city and each city may have been lived in by more than one person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to relate two Persons to the same City when by using @OneToMany annotation on the Person class you are saying that each City only will relate to one single Person.

Possible solutions:

1 - (Most recommended) Move @OneToMany annotation to the City class. Instead of having a Set of Cities on Person, implement a Set of Person on the class City. Also, adding the @OneToMany annotation on the Set of Person attribute.

2 - You can simply use the @ManyToMany annotation and leave all the rest like it is. This is not recommended because in your case it does not make sense to have a many-to-many between Person and City

Comment: Wouldn't _option 1_ mean, that every person has only _one_ city her or she has lived in? From my point of view only option 2 makes sense here.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke , you are right. It depends on his application domain. If he needs to keep records of all the cities one person has lived then option 2 is the correct one. But if only a person's current city is needed, then option 1.

Comment: That's not my use case. I need to be able to get a listing of people and from individual person entity found out which all (multiple) cities they have lived in. So the look up is for person class and then the person entity needs a reference back to set of cities. In option 1 I lose the reference from person to city. How can I express my use case properly. It seems like a simple enough use case. Only thing I can think of is may be to use bi directional relationship.

Comment: What you need to do then is to use option 2. But also create a @ManyToMany annotated Set<Person> in the class City. And then, when the method person.addCity(City city) is called you also call city.addPerson(this)

Comment: @adeelmahmood this article has an example of what I am saying https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytomany-unidirectional-bidirectional/ I hope it helps

Comment: I ended up using option 2. It just required me to remove cascade.all from ManyToMany. That seems to work fine.